# Cocos2d: Check if a CCNode/CCSprite is on the display list

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

In ActionScript, I can just check the `.stage` property of a `DisplayObject`, and if it's `null`, then the `DisplayObject` isn't on the display list. Is there a cocos2d equivalent?

I'm controlling my own touch system for buttons etc, and I want a quick way to ignore buttons that are registered but not actually on the screen. I'm currently checking against `visible` and `parent`, but that doesn't go all the way up the chain, so if I have a popup in memory that's not visible/attached to anything, and a button as a child inside that popup, the button check will pass (as it's visible and has a parent).

Aside from looping all the up until the scene, is there an easy way to check if a `CCNode/CCSprite` is on the display list?

**Edit**

Working on @HariKrishna's answer, this was the code I came up with as the cocos2d-x implementation wasn't exactly what I was looking for (e.g. if the `parent` of the node was `nil`, then it would return `YES` as it would never enter the check):

```
- (BOOL) hasVisibleParents
{
    CCNode * p = self.parent;
    while( true )
    {
        if( p == nil || !p.visible )
            return NO;
        if( [p isKindOfClass:[CCScene class]] )
            return YES;
        p = p.parent;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: pretty much the only way to do this is to set the menu.enabled property to NO when pushing it out of view, and YES when it becomes visible and usable again. Prefer that property to the .isTouchEnabled property of the parent class (CCLayer).  CCMenu will then ignore any touch events and not dispatch to the underlying menu items (buttons). There is no such thing as a 'display list' in cocos2d, afaik.

Comment: I'm not using `CCMenu` or `CCMenuItem` because it's super heavy for our use case - in our system, any `CCNode` can register with a `TouchManager` and so each object performs a hittest with the touch location - hence the need for a quick out if the `CCNode` isn't on the display list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CCNode::isVisible() and CCControl::hasVisibleParents() which will internally go up to  all the node hierarchy...

Thats the closest you can get for the same.

Example:

```
bool presentInDisplayList() {
if(isVisible() && hasVisibleParents())
    return true;
else
    return false;
}
```

Where hasVisibleParents() is, (Copied from Cocos2d-X Library)

```
bool CCControl::hasVisibleParents()
{
    CCNode* pParent = this->getParent();
    for( CCNode *c = pParent; c != NULL; c = c->getParent() )
    {
        if( !c->isVisible() )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This can be easily translated to Objective-C

Comment: I'm guessing `hasVisibleParents()` is only in cocos2d-x, as it doesn't seem to exist in cocos2d-iphone :/ - Does it automatically stop checking when it reaches the Scene (as the Scene's `parent` is `null`)?

Comment: Yes it will stop at Scene.. Also you can write the method for hasVisibleParents().. Check modified answer...

Comment: So I got around to implementing this - see my modified question - I had to change the code as it this wasn't really working for what I was looking for :D - if the `parent` is `NULL`, then this will return `true`. If you check for `null`, then it will return `false` all the time, as the `Scene` doesn't have a parent